# Xen alternative for VMware Infrastructure

Tags: virtualization, xen, interface

Is there any Xen alternative for VMware Infrastructure?

Any aggregation and control interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check ganeti from google.

> Ganeti is a cluster virtual server management software tool built on top of existing virtualization technologies such as Xen or KVM and other Open Source software.

[Ganeti site](http://code.google.com/p/ganeti/)

Next you my check:

Eucalyptus Management

Next to try:

DTC Xen
Tycoon
Hyperic - its like nagios
Bixdata programs

Some of them are only console management but some have nice GUI. Maybe one from them will be useful for you.
Sorry, I can post only one link :(

Comment: DTC XEN is the best tool I've ever seen! Provisioning (Data/IP) creation, restart .... nearly everything is supported! THX! 

For anyone interested: http://www.gplhost.com/software-dtc-xen_2-features.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go the open source route, you have [Convirt](http://www.convirture.com/) and [Enomalism](http://www.enomalism.com/)

If you go the Citrix way, you have the [XenCenter](http://xenserver5.com/xencenter.php) which looks very much like VMWare infrastructure. If you need entreprise level features, this is what you really should be using.

Comment: I agree. I've used both VMWare Infrastructure and XenCenter and Citrix XenCenter is a great alternative. Both (XenCenter/XenServer) are free but if you want to add more features there are additional costs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out RHEV